# VXMBA bm-700 microphone low sound

Tags: windows-7, audio, desktop-computer, microphone

My english is not the greatest, but I hope you can still catch what I'm trying to say.

I recently bought a new desktop microphone for my pc, but When I was talking to my friends in skype they could barely hear me and I needed to put the mic like 5 cm away from my mouth to get a descent volume. I read in the description of the product that I needed a Phantom power supply, but how much would that help? I'm not looking for better quality I just want to be able to talk further away from the microphone.

I've tried plugging it in to each diffrent slot in the pc, mic-in jack and USB ports, brought up the volume in all "programs", whenever I try something new it feels like the sound is getting lower for each time.

So yeah, I'm just using this for communication and have no plans in recording or streaming anything.

Anyone have a clue how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The setting `Automatically adjust microphone settings` in Skype usually causes this behavior. Disable it if it isn't and after that set the volume high manually.

Comment: I have tried that aswell without any luck or diffrence